# Counting an event in an alternating sequence

Tags: javascript, events, sequence

I have to write a lab that counts the longest sequence of heads and tails in 10,000 coin flips. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Hints?

Comment: What do you mean by "counts the longest sequence of heads and tails" ? Could you elaborate a bit please ?

Comment: in the sequence HTHTTTHTHHHHT there is a sequence of 3
tails and a sequence of 4 heads. I used a dice class and modified it so that it would only have an output of 1 or 2 and made 1=heads and 2=tails.

Comment: @dwarfy: A sequence of the same value, so in `HHTTTHTHHT` (where `H` = head, `T` = tail), the longest sequence of heads is 2, and the longest sequence of tails is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an outline of the algorithm you might implement:

1. Declare four variables: numberOfHeads, maximumNumberOfHeads, numberOfTails, and maximumNumberOfTails
2. Pick a random number between 0 (heads) and 1 (tails).
3. If the number is 0:
4. increment numberOfHeads
5. if numberOfTails is greater than maximumNumberOfTails set maximumNumberOfTails to numberOfTails.
6. set numberOfTails to 0.
7. If the number is 1:... the same as 4-6 but for the opposite variables.
8. Repeat 10,000 times then print/alert/somehow show the two maximums.

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some pseudocode for you:

```
biggest_yet = 0;
counter = 0;

if this_flip = last_flip
    counter++;
    if counter > biggest_yet
        biggest_yet = counter;
    end if
end if
```

Comment: You should reset your counter if `this_flip == last_flip` evaluates to `false`. ;)

Comment: Sorry, but still not correct. You will "miss" the first flip in a row, if resetting counter to 0.

Comment: @themorph - for crying out loud, this is psuedocode. I didn't even specify a "flip coin" routine. It's good enough to get the idea across... the OP is smart enough to figure out details.

Comment: @eykanal - Thanks for insulting me. Pseudocode depicts an algorithm in a more abstract way than source code does. Nevertheles this is no excuse for a broken algorithm. Would you print manuals with broken procedures with the excuse the user is smart enougth? Where is the use in guidance if it's simply wrong?

Comment: @themorph - no insult intended, but you're taking this too seriously. The provided code is obviously incomplete - as I said, there's no flip coin routine - and there is much to be done. The OP asked for "hints", and I provided that. This code is not "simply wrong", it's "simply incomplete."

Answer (score 2):

Here some pseudocode if you need to track both the longest sequence of heads and tails.

```
longestTail = 0;
longestHead = 0;
counter = 0;

if (flip == lastFlip)
  counter++;
  if (flip.isTailFlip AND counter > longestTail)
    longestTail = counter;
  else if (counter > longestHead)
    longestHead = counter;
  end if
else
  counter = 1;
end if
```

Take care that for the first flip `flip = lastFlip` evaluates to `false`. I ommited the output. Hope it helps. If have further questions feel free to ask. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The point of the exercise may be to make an efficient function -

perhaps by quitting when the largest run of heads or tails
is greater than the number of tosses left.

Run=window.Run || {};

```
Run.countmaxflips=function(n){
    n= n || 10000;
    var str= '', L= 0, temp, tem, run, max= 0,
    toss= [[0, 0], [0, 0]];
    while(L<n){
        temp= Math.round(Math.random());
        ++toss[temp][0];
        if(tem!=undefined && tem!== temp){
            run= toss[tem][0];
            if(run> toss[tem][1]) toss[tem][1]= run;
            toss[tem][0]= 0;
            if(max<run) max= run;
            if(L+max >n)L= n;
        }
        tem= temp;
        ++L;
    }
    if(toss[0][1]=== max) str= max+' tails in a row ';
    if(toss[1][1]=== max){
        if(str) str+= ' and ';
        str+= max+' heads in a row';
    }
    return str;
}
Run.countmaxflips(10000)

/*  returned values: (Strings)
11 tails in a row  and 11 heads in a row
14 heads in a row
15 tails in a row 
17 heads in a row
12 heads in a row
12 tails in a row 
12 tails in a row 
14 heads in a row
11 tails in a row 
14 tails in a row 
15 tails in a row 
11 tails in a row  and 11 heads in a row
13 tails in a row  and 13 heads in a row
13 tails in a row  and 13 heads in a row
15 tails in a row 
13 heads in a row
12 tails in a row 
11 tails in a row  and 11 heads in a row
15 heads in a row
13 tails in a row 
*/
```